# quickstart EF Migrations - InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured

Tags: identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations

I have a working MVC client accessing API based on quickstart. I am currently trying to replace the in-memory configuration and data with SQL Server by following the EF Migrations quickstart example. All of my db tables seem created and populated fine but when I run the client, I got a "InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured" error. My user id and password have not changed, and I watched the IdentityServer loads the predefined user info in debug mode. What else do I need to change for this to work again?

Here is my new ConfigureServices of IdentityServer

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
    const string connectionString = @"Server=.;Database=MyIDS;trusted_connection=True;";

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue - I needed to call .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() in ConfigureServices method. [This link helped a lot](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/375)